# Change Silverlight install URL?

Tags: silverlight

I'm writing a web application that might use Silverlight. Before we get the go ahead, Project Managers are wondering if we can change the install URL for Silverlight so that the install package can be hosted inside a local Sharepoint server.

In other words:

1. User browses our web app
2. User does not have silverlight installed.
3. User is redirected to install package (Its this we want hosted in a local sharepoint site)
4. User installs from our silverlight package
5. User is happy camper and now has silverlight installed

Is this possible, or do you have to get the install package each time from MS site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can,

if you look at the default.aspx (or html page) which hosts the silverlight object you will see a part where you set the link to download the silverlight installer. :

```
<a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50401.0" style="text-decoration:none">
   <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
 </a>
```

Just change the url to your Sharepoint Server File.

(You can event change what it displays when silverlight is not installed by changing the content of the  tag)

Comment: Thanks Danbord, this is great news!